# Extract Specific Text in BS

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I can't scrap the text after the "Product Description".

http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html

This is my code so far:

```
book_url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html'
response = requests.get(book_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
book_body = soup.find('article', class_='product_page')
```

Should I extract all the "p" tags before the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML IDs are unique (or at least should be), you should always use them when scraping if available, in your case the "product description" is under the id `product_description`:

```html
<div id="product_description" class="sub-header">
            <h2>Product Description</h2>
        </div>
```

So, to find the `id="product_description"` use:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


book_url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html'
response = requests.get(book_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
book_body = soup.find(id='product_description')
print(book_body.get_text(strip=True))
```

Comment: I see! I just add this in my code:
 ```
book_url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/1000-places-to-see-before-you-die_1/index.html'
response = requests.get(book_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
book_body = soup.find('article', class_='product_page')
product_description = book_body.find("div", {"id": "product_description"})
sinopse = product_description.find_next('p').getText()
```